# issue with rewriting the reduce method js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to rewrite the `reduce` method.

I have a couple of things I am unsure of. Firstly, is that it gives the wrong result, which I cannot figure out why. Secondly, if I don't assign the `reducez` function to a `const` or a `let` there is an error.

The following code gives an error

> Cannot read property 'reducuez' of undefined

Does anyone know why this is.

```js
[1, 2, 3].reducuez((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
});
```

And here is the actual code where I am trying to write the `reduce` method.

```js
Array.prototype.reducuez = function(callback) {
  let initialValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    initialValue += callback(this[i], initialValue)
  }
  return initialValue;
}

const y = [1, 2, 3].reducuez((a, b) => {
  return a + b;
});

console.log(y); // this is 11, should be 6
```

Comment: The code at the question does not have [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) signature.

Comment: @guest271314 what does that mean? That it takes more arguments?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a reduce method to return you a sum of items in the array ?

Comment: @peterflanagan The question states that the code is attempting to rewrite `Array.prototype.reduce()` though does not comport with the specification. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill for a polyfill for `.reduce()` and the link at the first comment for the actual specification.

Comment: I'm confused by the `undefined` error too.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, I don't know why this is. Maybe something to do with an initial value being returned? For everyone else, I am just trying to get an idea of what is happening under the hood with `reduce`. I am not trying to rewrite it exactly.

Comment: Note that if you wrap the statement (without the `const y`) in `{ }` then it works.

Comment: weird @Pointy I am not sure what is going on, that does work

Answer (score 2):

```
initialValue += callback(this[i], initialValue)
```

should be

```
initialValue = callback(this[i], initialValue)
```

because when you append values after every callback the the value of initalValue is added twice once in callback and once due to +=

```js
Array.prototype.reducuez = function(callback) {
  let initialValue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    initialValue = callback(this[i], initialValue)
  }
  return initialValue;
}

const y = [1, 2, 3].reducuez((a, b) => {
  return a + b;
});

console.log(y); // this is 11, should be 6
```

Comment: nice, and is the reduce method as simple as that. Besides the extras with the initial value etc? Also, why does it not work unless I assign to a variable?

Comment: It works without assigning to a variable too, but at every iteration it has to set a value for the accumulator so maybe you can return directly or using a variable. If you understand the concept behind it then it is easy!

Comment: I mean if you remove `const y` there will be an error. Is this not happening for you?

Comment: In this case there will be. I thought about the actual reduce function

Comment: Anyways, if it answered your question upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too

Comment: why is there an error, that is what I am asking. I am also wondering why this is. Your answer has helped , thanks